# Add custom attributes in 'SharePoint:FormField' tag in custom list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, custom-list

I have created a new custom list form (NewFormList.aspx) using Sharepoint designer.

Sharepoint will provide html controls (input, select,..) in below format.

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}" ControlMode="New"   FieldName="Title" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Title')}"/>
<SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff1description{$Pos}" FieldName="Title" ControlMode="New"/>
```

I want to customize and handle all the controls like 
adding Class="", Custom attributes, AngularJs directives in the form elements

```
<div ng-app="">
Name: <input type="text" ng-model="Name">
<!--Ex: I want to get the above input tag with ng-model directive  
<SharePoint:FormField ng-model="Name"></SharePoint:FormField> -->
My Name : {{Name}}
</div>
```

I have tried to add CssClass for adding class and custom attribute but sharepoint doesn't accept it.

I'm new to Sharepoint and looking for your help on how to handle this part.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

While not able to add custom fields, I decided to wrap the target input control with a  tag so that I can manipulate the target SharePoint Field by referencing it's parent:

```
<td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody" title="tdcompanynamezhi">

    <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff3{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="companynamechi" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff3',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@companynamechi')}"/>

 </td>
```